# Python time.sleep indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python's time module, there is a `sleep()` function, where you can make Python wait x seconds before resuming the program. Is there a way to do this indefinitely until a condition is met? For example:

```
while True:
    time.sleep()
    if x:
        break

time.unsleep()
```

I am trying to make a pause function for my PyGame program. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the thread *have* to sleep? From what it looks like, it doesn't have to - an infinite loop until the condition is met should suffice.

Comment: One way to pause (better than the type you would get from `sleep()`) is by setting a flag (`paused = True`) and not updating the game’s state `if paused`.

Comment: @Zizou212 that would cause the game to use 100% CPU while paused, which is rude (makes the computer slow and hot, uses electricity, and drains the battery - all for no reason). At least include a short sleep in the loop then.

Comment: Some relevance to answers at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20170251/1959808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
while not x: time.sleep(0.1)
```

will wait until `x` is true, sleeping a tenth of a second between checks. This is usually short enough for your script to seem to react instantly (in human terms) when `x` becomes true. You could use `0.01` instead if this is not quick enough. In my experience, today's computers are fast enough that checking a simple condition even every hundredth of a second doesn't really make a dent in CPU usage.

Of course, `x` should be something that can actually change, e.g. a function call.

Comment: 100ms and 10ms are both ridiculously slow

Answer (score 4):

Your code in the question implies that you want some other thread to resume your program. In that case you could use [`resumed = threading.Event()`](/library/threading.html#event-objects). You could create it in one thread and pass it into another:

```
while not resumed.wait(): # wait until resumed
    "continue waiting"
```

Call `resumed.set()` to resume this code immediately.

> I am trying to make a pause function for my PyGame program. Any help is appreciated.

Use [`pygame.time`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html). Typically, you have the main loop where you update the state of the game and at the end of the loop you call `clock.tick(60) # 60 fps`. It is enough to use `paused` flag in this case, to skip the updating.

Comment: A variation would be `forever = threading.Event(); forever.wait()`. This would be useful for a process whose only purpose is to handle interrupts (by setting handlers via [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)). See also: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gevent/Abtxtz3aZmQ/vrS7kTCqVY0J

Answer (score 0):

You could spin off a thread as follows:

```
import sys    
import time
from threading import Thread

prepare_to_stop = 0

def in_background_thread():
    while not prepare_to_stop:
        # Program code here
        print(prepare_to_stop)
        time.sleep(0.1)

try:
    th = Thread(target=in_background_thread)
    th.start()
    print("\nProgram will shut down after current operation is complete.\n")
    time.sleep(10**8)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    prepare_to_stop = 1

print("Program shutting down...")
```