# Repeat a command on SSH server forever, via Plink or a python script

Tags: python, ssh, putty

Perhaps a python script would work for this simple automation.
I need to connect via ssh to my router and run a command over and over. I understand that if I use Plink with a script I will probably have to repeat my command thousands of times. That would work but isn't there a better to just simply repeat the command?

For example, if i have to make a script my file would look like this:

```
/user/print
/user/print
/user/print
/user/print
/user/print
/user/print
/user/print
.....
```

Comment: You want something like `while true; do date; sleep 1; done` (replacing `date` with a command of your choice).

Comment: Should be tagged [tag:windows]

Comment: I tried making a cmd.txt with the following: while true; do /user/print; sleep 1; done. Then I start putty like this: C:\Program Files\PuTTY>putty.exe -t -m cmd.txt -load "mysesseion" -l root -pw mypsss. It starts the session, then gives me a syntax error.

Comment: And does your "router" have bash shell at all?

Comment: Yes, it is a Mikrotik router. it has an SSH console. If I make a cmd.txt with a hundred lines of:` /user print` it works, but stops after a hundred, I just need to make it infinite and a 5 second pause in between

Comment: Try running `uname -a` in your router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To do the loop on the server-side do:

  ```
  plink username@example.com "while true; /user/print; done"
  ```

  This has an advantage that you connect only once to the server.

- To do the loop on the client-side do:

  ```
  :loop
  plink username@example.com /user/print
  goto loop
  ```

  See also [How to create an infinite loop in Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5487473/850848)
- If you can do Python, just loop the `ssh.exec_command` call.

  ```
  import paramiko
  import time

  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.connect("example.com", username="username", password="password")

  while True:
      print "Running"
      stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/log print")
      print stdout.read()
      print stderr.read()
      print "Waiting"
      time.sleep(5)
  ```

  The above is combined code from:

  - [Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3586106/850848)
  - [How to run the Python program forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20170251/850848)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vassal](https://github.com/Shawn-Shan/vassal) package, which is exactly designed for this.

All you need is to install vassal and do

```
from vassal.terminal import Terminal
from vassal.scheduler import Scheduler
shell = Terminal(["ssh username@host", "cd scripts", "python foo1.py", "python foo2.py"])
shell = Scheduler(shell, sec=1)
shell.run()
```

This will run the command once every second, and you can make it run faster to change sec=0.1.