# how would I get this program to take input again for an unlimited amount of times after the output is displayed the first time?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, boolean

```
num = float(input('enter a number: '))

if num > 0:
    print('positive number')
elif num < 0:
    print('negative number')
elif num == 0:
    print('number is neither negative nor positive')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run the Python program forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170251/how-to-run-the-python-program-forever)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. If you don't want a number to exit, you can just ctrl-c:

```
while True:
  num = float(input('enter a number (999 to quit): '))
  if num == 999:
    break
  if num > 0:
      print('positive number')
  elif num < 0:
      print('negative number')
  elif num == 0:
      print('number is neither negative nor positive')
```