# how to put a whole script into a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 0 experience in coding but I put my ambition and code something in python for a game. Everything works perfect :D
But I have a problem. I don't know how to infinite repeat the code. I've look over the internet but i didn't understand much.
Im gonna let here a part of the code maybe someone can explain me how to put all code into 'repeat'.

```
import time
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(942, 642)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click(807, 581)
time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run the Python program forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170251/how-to-run-the-python-program-forever)

Answer (score 3):

Simply wrap it all (or, well, not the imports) in a `while True:` loop.

```
import time
import pyautogui

while True:
    pyautogui.click(942, 642)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(807, 581)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Already tried this and it says Error:expected an indented block.

Comment: This is Python – you'll need to make sure the code within `while True:` is indented like in my example.