# How to make this Python program repeat from the start? (Beginner help)

Tags: python, repeat

I do not know anything about Python but need to know how to make this program repeat (Go back to the top) when it has finished. Ignore mistakes they are there on purpose.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyY9V.png) How can this be done? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to put a whole script into a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320914/how-to-put-a-whole-script-into-a-loop)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)